# Please could someone advise on code format

Tags: python, for-loop, external-data-source

I originally had to write code to write 3 lines to an external text file called `output.txt`. The first line shows the minimal number of the first line, the second line will show the maximum number of the second line and the third line will show the average of the third line. no matter what numbers are input or length it will still show all the values of min,max and average.
The problem is the code is only writing the last average line to the output text file.

My lecturer would like the format to stay the same but he had these comments:

> The `min` and `max` lines are not being written to the output file.
>   This is because you do not write the values to the `report_line` variable, which stores the string to write to the output file.
>
> Try initializing `report_line` to be an empty string before the for loops begin.
>
> You can then use `+=` operator and new line characters to store the output in the `report_line` variable on each repetition of the for loop.

I tried them but I still get the same result. Only the avg line prints.

```
outfile = open("output.txt", "w")

with open("input.txt") as f:
    report_line = ""
    for line in f:
        operator, data =  line.lower().strip().split(":")
        line = line.split(":")
        operator = line[0].lower().strip()
        data = line[1].strip().split(",")
        newData = []
    for x in data:
        report_line+='n'
        newData.append(int(x))
        if operator == "min":
            result = min(newData)
        elif operator == "max":
            result = max(newData)
        elif operator == "avg":
            result = sum(newData) / len(newData)
            report_line = "The {} of {} is {}.\n".format(operator, newData, result)

outfile.write(report_line)

outfile.close()
```

The input:

```
min:1,2,3,4,5,6
max:1,2,3,4,5,6
avg:1,2,3,4,5,6
```

The output should be:

```
The min of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 1.
The max of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 6.
The avg of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 3.4.
```

Comment: Please show `input.txt` content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting your report_line on line 20. Change the `=` to `+=` instead

```
report_line += "The {} of {} is {}.\n".format(operator, newData, result)
            ^
```

You'd also want to indent the `for x in data` loop since you're currently only using the last operator, which is avg. You want to do the calculation for every line in your data

and you might want to remove this line since you're already adding newlines in your report_line statement

```
report_line+='n'
```

The fixed code would be

```
outfile = open("output.txt", "w")

with open("input.txt") as f:
    report_line = ""
    for line in f:
        operator, data =  line.lower().strip().split(":")
        line = line.split(":")
        operator = line[0].lower().strip()
        data = line[1].strip().split(",")
        newData = []
        for x in data:
            newData.append(int(x))
            if operator == "min":
                result = min(newData)
            elif operator == "max":
                result = max(newData)
            elif operator == "avg":
                result = sum(newData) / len(newData)
        report_line += "The {} of {} is {}.\n".format(operator, newData, result)

outfile.write(report_line)

outfile.close()
```

Comment: i get an error when running the code 'result' is not defined

Comment: Code works on the  input.txt you provided. If you have lines that are empty, or lines where there is a different operator, your operator == "something" checks are not passed and this the result is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Per your lecturer's comment, make sure to change all the `report_line` changes to `+=`. using `=` overwrites the existing value, throwing away any previous output. In particular, this line:

```
report_line += "The {} of {} is {}.\n".format(operator, newData, result)
#           ^
```

You'll need to add additional `report_line += ...` statements for the *min* and *max* cases. You're calculating the values but not adding them to `report_line`.

Or unindent the `report_line += ...` line above so it's not nested inside the *avg* case. If you unindent it then it'll apply to all three cases.

Furthermore, use `\n` for newlines. Change `report_line+='n'` to:

```
report_line+='\n'
```